# Event URL is downloaded instead of going to the url?

Tags: fullcalendar

There is several way to creating the event object that contains with URL attribute.
For example, array and json, ajax function.

But some reason, event url that is created in ajax function is not working properly and it is just downloading the url instead of going to the url.

However, event url within an array is working fine that supposed to be.

This following array is working well and go to the url when it is clicked.

```
var myEvents = {
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Expedition #1',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 30),
            allDay: false,
            url: '/community/wall/getWallContentAjax.do?itemId=391162080555'
        },
        {
            title: 'Quest #1',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 10, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 11, 0),
            url: '/community/wall/getWallContentAjax.do?itemId=391162080555'
        }
    ]

}
```

But this example that is located http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/ is not working properly but just download the link.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'example.xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start'),
                        url: '/community/wall/getWallContentAjax.do?itemId=391162080555'
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Both, array and ajax function is mostly working fine, except ajax event url is just downloaded into my computer instead of going to the url.

Any possible clue and advice will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

What you provided is not enough, how and where you are managing with url is not displayed , or not highlighted.
but i can suggest you one thing, try to put javascript , and call it,
like window.location.href="New_link"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [eventClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/) function like this :

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    // open events url property in a new window
    window.open(event.url, 'myeventurl');
    return false;
}
```

There is a [working example](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/gcal.html) in the demo section.